# AdMob GADBannerView not releasing and receiving ad requests when it shouldn't

Tags: uiview, admob

Here is my problem.
Also please not that I am aware of AdWhirl but choose not to use it because I prefer to have control over what is happening with my ads.

Basically I have iAds and AdMob. I start out always with iAds and if the ads have nothing to show I initialize AdMob and start showing it. Then when iAds finally gets something to show I hide Admob ads and destroy the view and display the iAds again.

This seems to work for 1 iteration meaning :

1. initialize iAds
2. iAds have no content to show
3. hide iAds
4. initialize Admob
5. Admob displays ads
6. 
7. iAds have received content so we should display it!
8. hide Admob
9. release the Admob view object

The problem is.. over time if I leave the app running and iAd fails to load ads a few times (meaning I do a bit of switching which results in creating Admob views) the released Admob view object is not being released and keeps receiving new ads even though it shouldn't.

Here is the code that I run whenever I receive a code 3 from iAds (meaning :The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable)

```
-(void) smartInitialize:(UIViewController*) theVC
{
    NSLog(@"AMOB :: smartInitialize");

    if(!initialized)
    {
        NSLog(@"AMOB :: PRE initialization");
        CGRect appFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
        UIView * theView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:appFrame];
        theView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        theViewController = theVC;
        //[theViewController retain];
        self.view = theView;
        [theView release];
        adMobAd = nil;
        adMobAd = [self requestNewAdmobView];
        if(adMobAd != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"AMOB :: adding ADMOBVIEW TO VIEW CONTROLLER!");
            [theVC.view addSubview:adMobAd];
            [adMobAd release];
        }

        initialized = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"AMOB :: POST initialization");

        if(adMobAd!=nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"AMOB :: adMobView is present, doing nothing...");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"AMOB :: reinitializing..");
            [self reinitializeAdmob];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the [self requestNewAdmobView] function :

```
- (GADBannerView*) requestNewAdmobView
{
    NSLog(@"AMOB :: requestNewAdmobView");
    CGRect adFrame = CGRectZero;
    NSString * appID = nil;
    adMobAd = nil;

    if(DEVICE_IPAD)
    {
        adFrame.size = GAD_SIZE_728x90;
        appID = @"id1";
    }
    else
    {
        adFrame.size = GAD_SIZE_320x50;
        appID = @"id2";
    }

    GADBannerView * tmp = nil;
    tmp = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:adFrame];

    if(tmp != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"AMOB :: adMobAD != nil , commencing with other stuff!");
        tmp.adUnitID = appID;
        tmp.rootViewController = gD.viewController;
        tmp.delegate = self;
        [tmp loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
        [tmp setHidden:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"AMOB :: adMobAD == nil , THIS IS BAD..");
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

Here is the [self reinitializeAdmob] function :

```
-(void) reinitializeAdmob
{
    NSLog(@"AMOB :: reinitializeAdmob");

    if(theViewController != nil)
    {
        [self shutdownAdmob];
        adMobAd = nil;
        adMobAd = [self requestNewAdmobView];

        if(adMobAd!=nil)
        {
            [theViewController.view addSubview:adMobAd];
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the [self shutdownAdmob]

```
-(void) shutdownAdmob
{
    NSLog(@"AMOB :: shutdownAdmob");

    if(adMobAd!=nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"AMOB :: adMobAd != nil, removing from superview and nilling...");
        adMobAd.delegate = nil;
        [adMobAd removeFromSuperview];
        //[adMobAd release];
        adMobAd = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"AMOB :: adMobAd == nil");
    }
}
```

Now from what I understand I am cleaning the GADBannerView called AdMobView correctly because :

1. at first it is == nil
2. then in [self requestNewAdmobView] i am allocing an instance so retain count = 1
3. I am returning it and then adding it to the viewControllers view and the view retains it so that makes the retain count go up to 2
4. I am then releasing the adMobView so I no longer own it and the retain drops down to 1
5. then when I want to get rid of the object completely in [self shutdownAdmob] i use the removeFromSupreview function which releases the view from the controller and thus it should dealloc it (I even tested this by subclassing the GADViewController and doing an NSLog upon deallocation and it does indeed dealloc).

Phew.. That's a lot of text sorry for that. So the question is : 
why does the admobview remove itself correctly the 1st time but durring the 2nd time it does not.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must release the adMobAd in shutdownAdMob.
The removeFromSuperview decreases the reference count of the adMobAd, but 
the count was incremented with addSubView, so you must release it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. I solved it by selecting this check[image]